# Fastest/Easiest way to store multiple arrays of data for multiple time steps

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure

I have particle ID, x-position, y-position, x-velocity, and y-velocity data for thousands of time steps. I would like to be able to use `find()` across multiple time steps. For instance to find all times and particles where the x- and y- velocities are below some value.

I started with an array of matrices to do this:

```
particles{t}(particleIndex,dataType)
```

so `particles{40}(:,2)` will give me the y-positions for all particles at time step 40
and `particles{50}(:,1)` will return the x-positions for all particles at time step 50.

This seemed like an unwieldy method of working with my data. I realized I can use an array of structures `particles(t).id`, `particles(t).xpos`, etc. I'm still having difficulty using `find()` across time steps and haven't been able to find any information to point me in the right direction. It seems from what I've read is that this also may not be the best choice either.

How should I store this data for my purposes, and can I use `find()` across time steps without iterating across them?

Answer (score 0):

Why not index via the particle id?:

```
particles = struct;
particles(id).t    % length(t)-by-1
particles(id).x    % length(t)-by-1
particles(id).y    % length(t)-by-1
particles(id).xdot % length(t)-by-1
particles(id).ydot % length(t)-by-1
```

Then `particles(id).x` is a vector where each element corresponds to an element in `particles(id).t`. `particles(1).x(1)` would be the first `x` value for `id` 1. However, the problem with breaking things up with an id is that you won't be able to search across particles. I'd really just use arrays (or a struct containing arrays for all particles):

```
particles = struct;
particles.ids  % 1-by-length(ids)
particles.t    % length(t)-by-1 or length(t)-by-length(ids)
particles.x    % length(t)-by-length(ids)
particles.y    % length(t)-by-length(ids)
particles.xdot % length(t)-by-length(ids)
particles.ydot % length(t)-by-length(ids)
```

Here `particles.ids` could be indexes in to the rows (or columns of the other arrays). Of course all of our particle trajectories need to be the same length (number of time-steps) in this case. This is similar to the structure output form of Matlab's ODE functions, e.g., `ode45`.

Comment: Also, `find` is often not need. I suggest learning about [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1), e.g., `xthresh = particles.x(particles.x > 1)`

Comment: Your first solution would make searching easier across time, which occurs much more frequently than I search across the particles. I can always iterate for this.

Comment: The first solution also easily permits vectors of different lengths. One would need to use cell arrays in the second version to handle that.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how your second solution would work with my data. The ID is unique to each particle, which has an x, y, xdot, and ydot for each t. I have my data in a format of x, y, particle ID, at t from a particle tracking library that I've been using. From there I separated the data into a matrix (or struct) for each time step. Are you saying that `particles.ids` would hold indexes to each `particles.x`, `particles.y`, etc.?

Comment: Yes. To obtain all of the `x` values for particle id 1 one would use `particles.x(:,particles.ids(1))`. Of course `particles.ids(1)` just returns `1` so this is equivalent to `particles.x(:,1)` - it's entirely superfluous. I wouldn't include it myself, but I added it because you previously had an `id` field. And, you didn't say, maybe your particle ids aren't numbered as indexes? There are other configurations where it might be less trivial and it still could be useful.